# Bijection between the set of normal series of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ and set of finite sequences of integers $>0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $a$ be an integer $>0$. By associating with every normal series
>   $(H_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ the
>   sequence $(s_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$, where $s_i=[H_{i-1}:H_i]$, a
>   one-to-one correspondence is obtained between the composition series
>   of $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ and the finite sequences $(s_i)$ of
>   integers $>0$ such that $a=s_1\ldots s_n$.

What is the codomain of this one-to-one correspondence? Is it $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N_{\geq1}}}\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}^{[1,n]}$?

Comment: As the quote says, the codomain is $\left\{\text{finite sequences $\left(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n\right)$ of positive integers such that $a = s_1 \cdots s_n$}\right\}$.